# Unable to format NVMe SSD to EXT4 but it is formatting in FAT32 and NTFS fine

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I am trying to format SSD to ext4 but it is not happening. When I try to format it to FAT32 or NTFS is works fine.

I had run the smart tool and found no problem. I have also clean formatted the disk but it is not working. Checked for bad blocks and found none. Also, did the `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvme0n1 count=16` and it works correctly.

When I format it to ext4, it gives input/output or invalid argument error after that SSD gets removed from disks but after restarting it appears again.

Please note SSD works fine if I format it as FAT32 or NTFS and I was able to store files in it but I am trying to install Linux into SSD which requires EXT4.

Comment: Which tool are you using to format it? What does `sudo parted /dev/XdY` report? (Also, `XdY`? NVME drives would follow the `nvmeXnYpZ` [disk>namespace>partition] pattern, not the `sda`/`hda`/`vdb`, etc. pattern.)

Comment: @muru yes I have updated the pattern. I am using `/dev/nvme0n1p1`. I tried to create partition with `sudo parted /dev/nvme0n1p1`, it works and then I formatted it using `mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p1` but it is giving this 
`Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: mkfs.ext4: Input/output error while writing out and closing file system`

Comment: @muru I have also used the disks and gparted tools. They give the same error.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant `sudo parted /dev/nvme0p1 p` (with a `p` at the end to print the partition info).

Comment: No problem @muru

Comment: It is displaying this with `sudo parted /dev/nvme0n1 p` -->
`Model: Lexar 250GB SSD (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      512B   250GB  250GB  primary
 2      250GB  250GB  512B   primary
`

Comment: And with `sudo parted /dev/nvme0n1p1 p` -->

`Error: /dev/nvme0n1p1: unrecognised disk label
Model: NVMe Device (nvme)                                                 
Disk /dev/nvme0n1p1: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
`

Comment: The only time you need dos/MBR/msdos partition table is if installing Windows in BIOS mode. Windows requires gpt partitioning for UEFI (since 2012). Try converting to gpt first. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/  or with gparted select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting.Many SSD also need firmware update to work or work correctly. Check version. `sudo apt install nvme-cli`  & `sudo nvme list` shows FW Rev. Compare to latest firmware revision available.